# Mysql taking too long for specific queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, cron

I am working on Codeigniter project and using Codeigniter Activerecord to access the database.

The problem is that the database table are accessed simultaneously by numerous cron jobs. Some queries on specific tables take too long, even when they are not accessed by any other cron job at same time.

[image]
As shown in this picture second query has taken 217 seconds while first one will finish in few seconds.

Code of second query (stuck one) is. There is not other query on this table

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('item_buyers');
$this->db->where('transaction_id',$transaction_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Why is this problem occuring. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do we have index on `transaction_id` column?

Comment: post us the output of you query like : EXPLAIN SELECT....

Comment: My car is broken. It is red and has 4 wheels. It can drive 190km/h. Please tell my why it won't start! You think my question lacks all information you need to help me? Well, yours does too. Indexes, your table definitions, other querys that might run, triggers, explains, table locks/transactions, your connection/code, all that can be a problem here. My best guess is a table lock/forgotten open transaction that waits for a timeout. Or you have no index and so many entries that a simple select would take 217s (your table will then have > 7GB @30MB/s) or you work on 5 1/4`` floppy disks.

Comment: @mitkosoft no index on transaction_id

Comment: @H_Z, this is a good start then. add index on that column and check is there any changes in performance.

Comment: @mitkosoft adding index on transaction_id will reduce the speed of insert and update commands on it and I am doing both.

Comment: if its taking 217 seconds then there is some other issue somewhere in your code or the database server has issues. in other words its not the database call. also if you come on stack for help - then at least try the things that people are suggesting. putting an index on transaction_id is the first logical  step to try.